# how to set width and height of sql command line output?

Tags: sql

I want to see the output in one line,i.e all columns should be side by side.

I have tried set pagesize 200,set linesize 200 but didn't get desired output in sql command line.How can I fix it?

Comment: You should add more details about your environment. Right now it is totally unclear what SQL quering tool are you talking about, thus it is impossible to give you answer.

Comment: I am guessing you are using Oracle and sql*plus. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Windows Command Prompt then left click on the windows icon and click properties. Set the Screen Buffer Size > Width = 3000. To persist this setting do the same under Defaults.

Comment: I really doubt OP is asking about Windows command prompt since it has neither "pagesize" nor "linesize" mentioned in his question.